# php convert datetime

Tags: php, date, time

Well i take from my database table something like:

`$datetime="2012-01-12 00:00:00"` i want to convert this variable/info to something like
`Mon, 02 Jan 2012 16:40:39 GMT` I want to put this info into my rss feed `<pubDate></pubDate>`

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @AdamWagner i didn't try anything, i didn't know `strotime function`

Comment: If you want to avoid down-votes and closed questions... you should  give your problem a good try first, then post your attempt along with your question.  That helps show good research effort, and will encourage more folks to provide good answers.  A quick look through the php manual's date-time functions, and you could've found this: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$datetime="2012-01-12 00:00:00";
$time=strtotime($datetime);
echo date("r",$time);
```

-or-

```
echo date("D, d M Y H:i:s T",$time);
```

Comment: +1 for `date("r", ...)`, that's probably what he actually needs.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with timezones though...

```
$tm = date("r", strtotime($datetime));
echo "<pubDate>".$tm."</pubDate>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting from human readable to machine readable to human readable again is not efficient.  If possible store as a Unix Timestamp and just use `date()`